# Does event.target contain unique position properties so that it's not necessary to create a custom element property with data-*?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

In the simple test code below I create a data property, `data-position` to assign each element a unique identifier.  I use these identifiers in the functions `labelShrink` and `labelGrow`to target the correct element after an event listener is triggered.  I looked through `event.target` and couldn't find any unique position identifiers that would allow me to get around creating a unique `data-*` property.  **Does a native property or method exist that would allow me to target an element without adding my own custom property?**

```js
'use strict';

var numberOfInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inputStyle').length;
var i;

for (i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.inputStyle')[i].setAttribute('data-position', i);
    document.querySelectorAll('.inputStyle')[i].addEventListener('focus', labelShrink);
    document.querySelectorAll('.inputStyle')[i].addEventListener('blur', labelGrow);
}

//this is where I use data-position
function labelShrink(event) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.inputLabel')[event.target.dataset.position].style.fontSize = ".75rem";
}

//this is where I use data-position
function labelGrow() {
    if (!document.querySelectorAll('.inputStyle')[event.target.dataset.position].value) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.inputLabel')[event.target.dataset.position].style.fontSize = "1.5rem";
    } 
}
```

```css
.inputLabel {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    padding: .25rem 0 0 .25rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    user-select: none;
    transition: font-size .25s;
}

.inputStyle {
    padding-top: 1rem;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-family: arial;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form class="formStyle">
            
    <div class="inputContainer">
        <div class="inputLabel">Phone Number</div>
        <input type="text" name="phoneOne" class="inputStyle">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="inputContainer">
        <div class="inputLabel">Secondary Phone Number</div>
        <input type="text" name="phoneTwo" class="inputStyle">
    </div>
            
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Don't use `<div class="inputLabel">`, but a proper `<label>`. With the `for` attribute, you can link it to your input.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use additional attributes you can access the .inputLabel through the **event.target.previousElementSibling**